# Applying PaddedForm to each element of any list with different dimentions

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a set of lists in any iteration

```
list[1]={{0.129627, 0.74633, 0.93636, 0.328093, 0.323795},{0.24651, 0.15002, 0.341932, 0.0734819, 0.596785}, {0.381849, 0.798165, 0.847398, 0.619787, 0.663031}};

list[2]={{0.577629, 0.756704, 0.330815, 0.873377, 0.268678},{0.0456685, 0.320828, 0.541756, 0.116326, 0.683982}};

list[3]={{0.7495, 0.513172, 0.882195, 0.184402, 0.442981}};
```

As it can be seen the `Dimensions` of every list is different from another. But I wish to apply the `PaddedForm[#,{2,3}]` to each number contained in a list. The desired results must be for example:

```
list[1]={{0.130, 0.750, 0.940, ...},{0.250, .....}, {0.390,....}};
.etc
```

I tried `PaddedForm[#,{2,3}]&list[1]` but it does not work. As long as I am not sure to use `Map` or `Mapthread` because in each iteration, the `Dimension` of the list is changing!

Comment: You can `Map` at `{-1}` level, check 3rd argument of `Map`. Or create `Listable` function.

Comment: btw, `PaddedForm` will work applied globally too, you just forgot `@`, check: `PaddedForm[#, {2, 3}] &@list[1]`

Comment: I could understand what you mean

Comment: Is there any way to not have a number as `0.000`? because for another list which is not written here I have `0.000` after applying that. For a number that results in as `0.000` it should be written `0`.

Comment: You can use `If`. or replace `0` with `"0"` before PaddedForm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PaddedForm` maps automatically:

```
PaddedForm[list[1], {2, 3}] // TableForm
```

[image]

```
PaddedForm[{list[1], list[2], list[3]}, {2, 3}] //TableForm
```

[image]